# App Scripting Cart Manipulation Access to category and products

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Is there a way to get access to the data loading services during cart manipulation in shopware 6.4. I use app scripting and would like to add a discount to the shopping cart. For the calculation, however, I need information of the category of items that are in the shopping cart.

`services.repository.search('category', criteria)` does not work because the repository service is missing in cart hook.

Answer (score 0):

That's currently not possible, and as of now this is on purpose, as the cart process should finish fast, and with giving access to the repos there that would have a pretty big negative impact on performance there.